# Speed up double for loop PyGame draw

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I have a pygame game and it is currently bottlenecking in the Draw to screen process. This is the code (pg is pygame):

```
def draw_living_cells(self):
    self.screen.fill(BLACK)
    for x in range(0, GRID_WIDTH + 1):
        for y in range(0, GRID_HEIGHT):
            if self.grid[x + 1][y + 1] == 1:
                pos = (int(x * CELL_SIZE), int(y * CELL_SIZE), int(CELL_SIZE), int(CELL_SIZE))
                pg.draw.rect(self.screen, LIFE_COLOR, pos, 0)
    pg.display.flip()
```

I thought multiprocessing could help, but I'm not sure how to implement, if it is possible (due to possible shared memory issues) or if it would help at all.

This process takes about 20ms with a self.grid of size 200x150 in a 800x600 display. I think its odd to have ~50fps in such a simple process.

Comment: *"I thought multiprocessing could help"* - No. You have to do all the drawing in a single thread (pygame is based  on OpenGL ES).

Comment: You could add `clock.tick(FPS)` to improve performance instead

Comment: `SDL` which `pygame` is based on is very slow when it comes to this things.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you modify your code to use pygame's Sprite mechanics and in particular look at the sprite group `pygame.sprite.DirtySprite`. You can then mark the cells that have changed as dirty and have it only redraw those cells instead of all the cells.

This change would also require you to not redraw the entire background with the `self.screen.fill(BLACK)`.

Since your method is named `draw_living_cells()`, that implies that there are dead cells that you do not redraw. Since you would not be filling the entire background that means that you have to draw the background onto the screen where the dead cell used to be.

This of course only helps if some the of the cells do not change each pass. Otherwise you are just adding overhead without saving drawing.

Though I recommend Sprites and pygame.sprite.DirtySprite, you can of course do something similar yourself by just marking your cells and doing that yourself in your redraw.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pygame.PixelArray`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html) for direct pixel access of the target [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html). Set the pixels directly, instead of drawing each cell separately by [`pygame.draw.rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect):

```py
def draw_living_cells(self):
    self.screen.fill(BLACK)

    pixel_array = pg.PixelArray(self.screen) 

    size = self.screen.get_size() 
    for x in range(0, GRID_WIDTH + 1):
        for y in range(0, GRID_HEIGHT):
            if self.grid[x + 1][y + 1] == 1:
                rect = pygame.Rect(x * CELL_SIZE, y * CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE)
                pixel_array[rect.left : rect.right, rect.top : rect.bottom] = LIFE_COLOR

    pixel_array.close()

    pg.display.flip()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it and got 0-5% improvement, if any.

Comment: @OliverMohrBonometti I see. It was just a try.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I tried something similar to what Glenn suggested. I used numpy to obtain where the living cells are and then iterate through those coordinates instead of the whole grid. This gave 2.5~3x performance increase. New Code:

```
def draw_living_cells(self):
    self.screen.fill(BLACK)

    living_cells_xy = np.where(self.grid == 1)
    living_cells = len(living_cells_xy[0])
    for i in range(0, living_cells):
        x = living_cells_xy[0][i] - 1
        y = living_cells_xy[1][i] - 1
        pos = (int(x * CELL_SIZE), int(y * CELL_SIZE), int(CELL_SIZE), int(CELL_SIZE))
        pg.draw.rect(self.screen, LIFE_COLOR, pos, 0)
    pg.display.flip()
```

Comment: Glad the advice helped.